# Spark dataframe: looking up elements of an array using a second dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe that has a list of ids for each row:

```
ident  list_of_ids
1      [3,4,5]
2      [5,6]
3      [2]
4      []
```

And a second spark dataframe that maps id to some text description:

```
id     desc
2      "aa"
3      "bb"
4      "cc"
5      "dd"
6      "ee"
```

Is there an easy (and fast) way to add a third column to the first dataframe with a list of descriptions corresponding to the ids in the list:

```
ident  list_of_ids  list_of_desc
1      [3,4,5]      ["bb", "cc", "dd"]
2      [5,6]        ["dd", "ee"]
3      [2]          ["aa"]
4      []           []
```

I know I could do a forEach on the second column and lookup based on each id but if the second table is big I suspect this will be extremely slow.

Answer (score 3):

You could first explode your list of ids, then join both Dataframes on their ids and finally collect the descriptions in lists.

Let's assume `df` is your first Dataframe and `dfDesc` contains the descriptions :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.withColumn("id", explode($"list_of_ids"))
  .join(dfDesc, Seq("id"))
  .groupBy($"ident", $"list_of_ids").agg(collect_list($"desc"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If your 2nd table is big and 1st table is relatively small, you can 1) create a dataframe of distinct ids from the 1st table and join using `broadcast` with the 2nd table to create a relatively small dataframe with the desc-mapped columns, and 2) join the two created dataframes and use `groupBy`/`collect_list` to generate the result:

```
val df1 = Seq(
  (1, Seq(3, 4, 5)),
  (2, Seq(5, 6)),
  (3, Seq(2)),
  (4, Seq())
).toDF("ident", "list_of_ids")

val df2 = Seq(
  (2, "aa"),
  (3, "bb"),
  (4, "cc"),
  (5, "dd"),
  (6, "ee")
).toDF("id", "desc")

val df1Exploded = df1.select($"ident", explode($"list_of_ids").as("id"))

val df1Distinct = df2.join(broadcast(df1Exploded.select($"id").distinct), Seq("id"))

val dfResult = df1Exploded.join(df1Distinct, Seq("id")).groupBy($"ident").
  agg(collect_list($"desc").as("list_of_desc"))

dfResult.show
+-----+------------+
|ident|list_of_desc|
+-----+------------+
|    1|[bb, cc, dd]|
|    3|        [aa]|
|    2|    [dd, ee]|
+-----+------------+
```